# php establishing connection fails

Tags: php, sql

I am trying something very basic yet it is failing to work for some reason! well basically I am trying to create a new username and password for my site. It is only for testing. When I submit the request, I get this:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'santoshs'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/khali197/public_html/test/enroll.php on line 27

I have no idea who is santoshs that is showing here @ localhost. From home it shows someone different. What could it be?

I've got the following code to try achieve my objective...all pretty simple really:

```
<?php
class ServerConnection{

    function connect(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dsdssd_admin", "sddsdsd", 
 "khadsdsli197_dsd");
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . 
$mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .
                    $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
        //echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

    }
}
?>
```

the register.php form:

```
<form name="register" action="enroll.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" />
Password Again: <input type="password" name="pass2" />
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

and the form to handle that, i.e. enroll.php:

```
<?php
include("ServerConnection.php");

//retrieve our data from POST
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
if($pass1 != $pass2)
    header('Location: register_form.php');
if(strlen($username) > 30)
    header('Location: register_form.php');

$hash = hash('sha256', $pass1);

//creates a 3 character sequence
function createSalt()
{
    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($string, 0, 3);
}


$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);
$connection = new ServerConnection();
$connection->connect();
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, salt )
        VALUES ( '$username' , '$hash' , '$salt' );";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Any help here would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: is your login username `santoshs` ?

Comment: not it is not that's why I am shocked

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is not MySQLi. If you're using the MySQLi extension, don't use the `mysql_real_escape_string` function. They're two entirely different database drivers.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the mysql_real_escape_string() function it searches for earlier *mysql* connection opened, NOT *mysqli* connection. If it can not find it tries to open a new connection with system login user. If your system username is `santoshs` then this is the reason.

The solution would be to **change the `ServerConnection` class to use `mysql` extension or use the mysqli extension in `enrole.php`**

Comment: Correction: if there is no previously established mysql connection, the `mysql_*` function will try to automagically establish a new connection with a best-guess username right then and there.

Comment: `best-guess username` you mean, currently logged in username ?

Comment: I think so. You can also configure defaults in the php.ini I think. Either way, it's a pretty horrible mechanism. :)

Comment: @Shiplu hmmm so why do I get these random users@localhost when I am trying to connect to database and what can I do to get rid of this issue?

Comment: What is your login user name? and what is the value of `mysql.default_user` and `mysqli.default_user` in `php.ini` ?

Answer (score 0):

That you're seeing the error when calling mysql_real_escape_string() implies you've not trapping the error at mysql_connect() - so even before considering what the user is, it's evident that the code which is running is not the code you've shown us.

Try adding some error detection at mysql_connect() in ServerConnection.php and check the permissions for the user santoshs

Comment: Where are you seeing `mysql_connect`?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on but I believe now that mysqli or more like ServerConnection class was causing the issue. I will examine that further because once I changed it to regular mysql connect, suddenly all worked! Thanks though.